# Scala SBT is not able to download dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am new to Scala and Akka. I have created a new project and below is my build.sbt file.

```
name := "akka_essentials"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

val akkaVersion = "2.5.13"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion,
  "com.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
)
```

The sbt tool is not able to download dependencies. The error log is as below:

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.13:2.5.13
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\Anand\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.akka\akka-testkit_2.13\2.5.13\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-testkit_2.13/2.5.13/akka-testkit_2.13-2.5.13.pom
[error] Error downloading com.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:3.0.5
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\Anand\.ivy2\local\com.scalatest\scalatest_2.13\3.0.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/scalatest/scalatest_2.13/3.0.5/scalatest_2.13-3.0.5.pom
[error] Error downloading com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.13:2.5.13
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\Anand\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.akka\akka-actor_2.13\2.5.13\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.13/2.5.13/akka-actor_2.13-2.5.13.pom
```

I am very new to Scala. I have not defined anything like ivy.xml. I am from Java background and generally use Gradle. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Akka `2.5.13` has not been cross published for Scala `2.13` as you can [check on Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.12/2.5.13).

The earliest version supporting 2.13 (release, not milestone or RC) is [2.5.23](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.13/2.5.23). You can see the version matrix for Actors [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor).

So you need to use newer Akka or older Scala.

With Scalatest you used wrong organization. It's `"org.scalatest"` not `"com.scalatest"`.

If you have doubts about dependency resoultion check Maven first.

Comment: Hi I tried various versions of akka, like akkaVersion = "2.5.23" but when i build the project, it still gives error:not found: object akka
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

Comment: Have you `reload`ed sbt? Did `update` succeeded? Do you see these errors in console or in IDE? If in IDE did you reload sbt setup after changing version?

Comment: Same for scalatest. Support to Scala 2.13 started at 3.0.8

Answer (score 0):

I did the following changes to make it work:

```
name := "project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

val akkaVersion = "2.5.13"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion
 // "com.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
)
```